# I had to add a dummy parameter to BaseClass when using super().__init__() & don't know why

Tags: python-3.x, super

In the example code below I have added a 'dummy' parameter into BaseSensorClass to make it work.  I don't understand why this is necessary.

I am writing some code to read sensor information for sensors of a few different type, so I created a BaseSensorClass with the common parameters and child classes for the sensor types.  The example is simplified and just has a temperature sensor.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():
    s1 = TemperatureSensorClass(123,'first',  99.9)
    s2 = TemperatureSensorClass(234,'second', 22.2)
    print('s1 name = ',  s1.name,  ' id = ',  s1.id, ' temperature = ', s1.temperature)
    print('s2 name = ',  s2.name,  ' id = ',  s2.id, ' temperature = ', s2.temperature)

class BaseSensorClass:
    def __init__(self, dummy, id = 0, name = 'noname'):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class TemperatureSensorClass(BaseSensorClass):
    def __init__(self, id = 0, name = 'x', temperature = 0):
        super().__init__(self, id, name)
        self.temperature = temperature
        print('TemperatureSensorClass called with name=',  name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expected it to work without the 'dummy' parameter, but if I remove it I get an error TypeError: **init**() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing `self` into `__init__` manually. As with python instance methods, the reference to the object is automatically passed in. Doing `super().__init__(a, b)` more or less does `<super class>.__init__(self, a, b)`. When you pass `self` in manually, you end up passing it into the constructor twice, which is why you're getting four positional arguments.

The following code works and doesn't use `dummy`:

```
def main():
    s1 = TemperatureSensorClass(123,'first',  99.9)
    s2 = TemperatureSensorClass(234,'second', 22.2)
    print('s1 name = ',  s1.name,  ' id = ',  s1.id, ' temperature = ', s1.temperature)
    print('s2 name = ',  s2.name,  ' id = ',  s2.id, ' temperature = ', s2.temperature)

class BaseSensorClass:
    def __init__(self, id = 0, name = 'noname'):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

class TemperatureSensorClass(BaseSensorClass):
    def __init__(self, id = 0, name = 'x', temperature = 0):
        super().__init__(id, name)
        self.temperature = temperature
        print('TemperatureSensorClass called with name=',  name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```